# Bayesian inference problem with three parameters

Tags: r, bayesian, poisson-distribution, posterior

Assume that I observe a yearly time series for the number of certain events occurring per year. Also, assume that the data points come from a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$.

The dataset in question is the dataset `coal` in the `boot` package.

```
library(boot)
data(coal)

x <- 1851:1962
y <- tabulate(floor(coal[[1]]))
y <- y[x]
plot(cumsum(y)~x,type='l') #cumulative
```

[image]

Now, assume that there is a changepoint $t_1$ in the time series whereby points before $t_1$ are generated by a Poisson process with parameter  $\lambda_1$ and points on or after are generated by a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda_2$.

I'm trying to perform Bayesian inference on the parameters $\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$ and $t_1$ to obtain the posterior distributions.

I'm bound to use the following priors: $\lambda_1$ $\sim \Gamma(2,1)$, $\lambda_2$ $\sim \Gamma(2,1)$ and $t_1\sim U(1851,1960)$.

how can I approach this task using direct sampling methods?